# Java post http request (express) REST api

Tags: java, api, http, post, express

Having some troubles communicating with a Express REST api through Java.

A simple route which is online at: http://localhost:5555/test

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("recived request");
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

As you can see, this route doesn't do much tho, only for connection testing purpose.

Spending like hours searching but didn't find a good example yet.

Still got this peace of code but got exception.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:5555/test");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write("test");
```

If someone knows a peace of code I could work, that would be great!

Thanks

**Edit**
Server is running:

```
> node index.js
server running on port: 5555
connection open
```

Exception from Java:

```
System.err: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Express route is expecting a `POST` and your code does a `GET` request (`openConnection`). Try to change it to `get` an retry your operation.

Comment: Can you give any more feedback in the error you get and update your question so others can help?

Comment: I would advise you to use Apache HttpClient library, see examples here: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request

Comment: I thought this was deprecated? Using HttpClient & HttpPost

Comment: It is a different and very widely used library to make HTTP requests in Java, it is not deprecated at all.

Comment: Ah my NetBeans says so, Ill look into it thanks for thinking with me here!

Comment: The aim is help, but consider an upvote once you get something to work. Also, update your question with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Because your route accepts `POST` method, you may have 2 options.

1. Change your request method in Java code to `POST`

   ```
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   ```
2. Change your route accepts `GET`

Comment: Hi, updated my post. Forgotten to setRequestMethod in previous code but won't work either..

Comment: Well, I have some suggestions for you: 1. you should use some logger to help you debug the procedure of requesting; 2. check your firewall; 3. Use browser or `Postman` from chrome app to verify if your server is correctly setup before proceeding.